# Perforce -Keep working on the project while the code is under review

Tags: perforce

I am a git person. In git, after I finishing a little feature, I will submit the branch to review and start a new branch to work on new features.

For example, I had submitted a code recview for feature A, and it is still under review. At this time, I want to start working on feature B, assuming feature A's code will be merged in the near future. In Git, typically I just create a new branch to work on the new feature, if there is some problem with feature A I can easily switch back to branch A to fix it and merge the fixed version to my new feature branch.

How's it achieved in perforce? Should I copy the whole code somewhere as a way to manage branch myself?

Comment: You might need to clarify your question.  What does your review process look like that you're blocked from continuing to work on your branch while an earlier change is under review?  I've never seen a review process implemented in Perforce that would block work while a review is under way.

Comment: Please see my edit in the question.

Comment: You should definitely *not* copy the whole code somewhere as a way to manage the branch yourself. Use your SCM system's features instead!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Perforce exactly the same way you'd do it in Git, if you like -- create your feature B branch and work on feature B there.  If you need to make changes to your feature A branch, those can be merged back to your mainline and/or your feature B branch.

If you do your code reviews as shelves, you can have any number of them in development at a time; a shelved change is effectively "rebased" onto submitted changes when you sync+resolve.

FWIW, usually the way I've done reviews in Perforce is to make my changes on my own development branch, set up the merge to the mainline, and then shelve that for review.  That way I can continue work on my development branch uninterrupted, I don't need to create a new branch, and if there's a fix needed to my merge-in-progress I can just amend the shelved change (either by submitting the fix to my branch and adding it to the merge, or making the edit as part of the merge operation); it also has the benefit of making conflict resolution (if any) part of the change under review.